# Where does the word "News" come from?

Tags: etymology, history

I'm just wondering where does the word "News" come from. Is it from the word "New" which means things that did not exist before?

Comment: It means "things that will be new to you," i.e., things you haven't heard yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It derives from the French "nouvelles", literally "new things". Its usage regarding radio program is from 1923:

***[News](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=news%20&searchmode=none):***

> - ***late 14c., "new things," plural of new (n.) "new thing," from new (adj.); after French nouvelles,***  used in Bible translations to render Medieval Latin nova (neuter plural) "news," literally "new things." Sometimes still regarded as plural, 17c.-19c. Meaning "tidings" is early 15c.
> - ***Meaning "radio or television program presenting current events" is from 1923.***  Bad news "unpleasant person or situation" is from 1926. Expression no news, good news can be traced to 1640s. Expression news to me is from 1889.

(Etymonline)

***[News](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/01/the-origin-of-the-word-news/)***:

The word commonly used before "news"  came into usage was "***tidings***" which meant "announcement of event":

> - The word news can be traced back to late Middle English around the 14th century as a plural for the adjective “new” or “new thing”.  ***This is a somewhat rare instance of an English adjective becoming a noun when made plural.***
> - ***Making this leap from “new” to “news” in English is thought to have been influenced by the Old French “nouveau”, meaning “new”.  “Nouveau” in its plural feminine form becomes the noun “nouvelles”, meaning “news”.***
> - ***Before the 14th century, instead of using the word “news”, English speakers typically used the word “tidings”, more or less meaning the “announcement of an event”***.  This Middle English version started before the 11th century and stems from the Old English term “tidung” meaning “Event, occurrence, or a piece of news”.

(todayifoundout.com)