# NEWS - not certain where this word is derived from

Tags: meaning

NEWS could this word be derived from:
N orth
E ast
W est
S outh

The news comes from the four points of the globe.

Comment: like the north/south pole, and the east/west ...?

Comment: A dictionary should be able to give you the etymology for this quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

OED has that it's an ordinary plural of *new:*

> **Origin:** Formed within English, by conversion; modelled on a French lexical item. **Etymon: new** *n.*
>
> **Etymology:** Specific use of plural of ɴᴇᴡ *n.,* after Middle French *nouvelles* (see ɴᴏᴠᴇʟ *n.*), or classical Latin *nova* new things, in post-classical Latin also news (from late 13th cent. in British sources), use as noun of neuter plural of *novus* new (compare classical Latin *rēs nova* (feminine singular) a new development, a fresh turn of events). Compare later ɴᴏᴠᴇʟ *n.*
>
> The synonymous Dutch *nieuws* (16th cent. as het nieuws ‘the news’) probably originated in Middle Dutch and early modern Dutch constructions with the genitive singular, as *iet nieuws, wat nieuws* etc.; compare similar uses in English at ɴᴇᴡ *adj.*

It is interesting that *new* is no longer a count noun: OED shows that as obsolete — apart from a couple of whimsical 19th-century citations it appears to have died out in the sixteenth century. *New* does survive as a mass noun ("those things which are new"), but mass nouns can't generally be pluralised. *News* is now a distinct word standing on its own.

Comment: This answer uses [real small capitals](https://yaytext.com/small-caps/), which I can see in Chrome, Edge and the Android app. If you see something else using a modern browser, please comment.

Comment: Tsk. And you a mod! :) I'm not sure I agree that the ["original"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282683/where-does-the-word-news-come-from) really should have been closed though. And presumably you're of like mind.